# Como sumar varios numeros en Javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Buenas como están? Tengo una pregunta de como puedo hacer que un valor en javascrip pueda sumarla una y otra vez , es decir que por ejemplo pueda hacer que 1 + 1 + 1 sea igual a 3 sin tener que crear una variable para cada uno de ellos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la calculadora que estoy haciendo y cada boton tiene un simbolo ahora lo que yo quiero hacer es que eso me arroje un resultado

Comment: tienes algo de código de lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: bueno estoy haciendo una calculadora y tengo una funcion que registra el boton que se presiono que es un numero y luego otra que registra el simbolo de la operacion llamese "+" "-" entonces quiero hacer que cada que elija un numero y una operacion se valla sumando para cuando le de a = se muestre un resultado

Comment: agregue una respuesta , talves es lo que andes buscando, saludos

Answer (score 1):

puedes escribir un string con la operación en un campo y con la funcion **eval** evaluara el string y te devolverá el resultado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <script>
        var num = 0;
        function evaluar() {
            var ev = document.getElementById("evaluar").value
    
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = eval(ev);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body >
         <input type="text" id="evaluar" value="1+1+1">
         <input name="suma" type="button" onClick="evaluar()" value="suma" />
         <p id="resultado"></p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Implementa un ciclo `for` e incrementas la variable:

```
var i;
var numero = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    numero ++;
    console.log(numero)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hola utiliza la funcion eval(cadena de texto) esto te dará el resultado que deseas ingresa toda la cadena de la operacion en la función eval

```
eval("2 + 2");             // devuelve 4
```